# Create custom utility referencing additional custom colors

Tags: tailwind-css

I have several custom utilities configured in my `tailwind.config.cjs` file this:

```js
plugins: [
    plugin(({ addUtilities }) => {
        const utilities = {
            '.border-invalid': {
                border: '1px solid #ef4444',
            },
            [...]
        };
        addUtilities(utilities);
    }),
],
```

I also have defined custom colors, like this

```js
extend: {
    colors: {
        'red-50': '#FEF2F2',
        [...]   
        'red-500': '#EF4444',
        [...]
    }
}
```

Instead of having the hard-coded value in my custom utility, I'd like to reference my custom color, so that if I ever change my color palette my custom utilities would be updated accordingly. So, ideally, it would be something like this:

```
const utilities = {
    '.border-invalid': {
        apply: 'border border-solid border-red-500',
    },
```

Or some way to reference `red-500` in my custom utility instead of the hard-coded `#EF4444`.

Is there a way to achieve it?

---

@ihar-aliakseyenka answer workes great, I added this just to tell that the second alternative, `border: "1px solid theme('colors.red-500')"` even show a nice and clear css definition when flying with the mouse over:

[image]

While the first option, `border:` 1px solid ${theme('colors.red-500')}` just show the literarl value (as expected, btw):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [theme()](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) directive

```js
plugins: [
    plugin(({ addUtilities, theme }) => { // extract theme
        const utilities = {
            '.border-invalid': {
                border: `1px solid ${theme('colors.red-500')}`, // concatenate
            }
        };
        addUtilities(utilities);
    }),
  ],

// or pass it as a string
plugins: [
    plugin(({ addUtilities }) => {
        const utilities = {
            '.border-invalid': {
                border: "1px solid theme('colors.red-500')",
            }
        };
        addUtilities(utilities);
    }),
  ],
```

> Note: you set your color as `red-500`, so no dot notation will be available like `theme('colors.red.500')` (it will cause error. Well maybe not because Tailwind has red-500 color but in any other cases it will)

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/t1denfSTTC?file=config)