# Building Multiple Default Tailwind Classes

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a series of tailwind classes for an application and have run into a problem with "default" colors for specific attributes.

We have a JSON file which contains all of our colors. We then pass this JSON file into the `presets` option in our `tailwind.config.js` file. For instance:

```json
{
    "theme": {
      "extend": {
        "neutral": {
          "accent": "#8C9FB8",
          "strong": "#0D192A",
          "weak": "#5F738B",
          "text": "#435469",
          "button": "#435469",
          "placeholder": "#8C9FB8",
          "background": "#EFF3F9",
          "background-weak": "#F7F9FC",
          "background-disabled": "#DDE5F0",
          "background-tooltip": "#304055",
          "background-strong": "#0D192A",
          "border": "#C6D1E1",
          "border-button": "#8C9FB8",
          "border-focus": "#6D89AF",
          "template-blend": "#5F738B"
        },
        "danger": {
          "background-medium": "#E01939",
          "background-weak": "#FFEBF0",
          "border-focus": "#EE707B",
          "border-pressed": "#E7445A",
          "accent":  "#E01939",
          "button": "#B7233C",
          "text": "#8E2637",
          "strong": "#5F232D"
        },
        "info": {
          "background": "#B7EBF9",
          "background-weak": "#E2F7FD",
          "border": "#60D1ED",
          "accent": "#41BEE0",
          "text": "#2A7085",
          "text-hover": "#2A7085",
          "strong": "#224752"
        },
       ...
    }
```

This approach works generally, however I'm struggling to figure out how to come up with proper *defaults* for various DOM elements that we want to style.

Currently, for instance, in order to style the text with our default text color, you'd have to write the class `text-neutral-text` because you have to specify which color to use from the `neutral` block. I'd like this to be `text-neutral` instead.

We could use a `DEFAULT` value, but that would also be applied for `border-neutral` which should be a different color.

Is it possible to have different defaults here per DOM element, or is there a better way of structuring our Tailwind configuration so that we can have these defaults?

Answer (score 1):

Create custom plugin and add these utilities manually. You need to do some job to read through the json file and extract the values from it, and define it too as utilities.

So here is the minimum process on how to do it, if you have the naming constant like `{variant}: {utility}-{option}: {value}`:

```js
const colors = {
  neutral: {
    accent: "#8C9FB8",
    ...
  },
  danger: {
    "background-medium": "#E01939",
    ...
  },
};
plugin(({ addUtilities, theme }) => {
  // extract theme
  const utilities = {};
  for (const variant in colors) {
    for (const utility in colors[variant]) {
      const [name, option] = utility.split("-");
      switch (name) {
        case "background":
          utilities[`.bg-${variant}${option ? `-${option}` : ""}`] = {
            "background-color": colors[variant][utility],
          };
          break;
        case "text":
          utilities[`.text-${variant}${option ? `-${option}` : ""}`] = {
            color: colors[variant][utility],
          };
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  addUtilities(utilities);
});
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183815/12348028) for more details.